# Search Engine security for searches associated with the same searcher

Tags: encryption

A number of years ago AOL leaked potentially identifiable information, because all of the searches leaked were associated with the same 'user', and as such they could be put together to identify the searcher. Search engines now claim they are cautious enough to encrypt their searches, but does that include seperating searches coming from the same IP address, or do they only encrypt the IP address? If they don't seperate the searches there is still a risk, because the content of the searches can be combined to identify a searcher if ever leaked, even if the IP address is masked.

Comment: I'm not sure that we can answer for all search engines. I can guess that Chinese search engines do keep the data correlated.

Answer (score 2):

There was a documentary I saw a few months ago on Netflix that told about how Google has data on everyone's searches. They showed an example of some guy who searched for numerous ways to kill his wife. He also searched for a good place to get a sandwich in the middle of his murder searches. So the documentary visits the guy and it turns out he was a writer for a crime tv show. And his wife is very much alive.

It's probably a good idea to assume that nothing you do on the Internet is a secret unless you go to great lengths to make it that way.

(I think the documentary was titled something like "terms and conditions may apply")